# hidden field value using javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I am loading a another page and a js file. The child page has a hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="eventOk" id="eventOk" value="" />
```

This child page has a an event which is setting value of this variable:

```
function onEndClientCallBack(sender, eventArgs) {              
            $('#eventOk').val('5')
            alert('1 value is' + $('#eventOk').val());        
        }
```

The alert is showing that value is set properly. Now I want to use this value inside the js file which is loaded in the frame but when I alert the value it shows blank value. how can I set the value in aspx page and use in js file ?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using traditional frames, or an iframe? If its an iframe have a look at this: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/09/access-iframe-content-using-jquery.html

Comment: I already used this and it is showing blank. It is not showing the new value which is modified by the onEndClientCallBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add runat="server" attribute to the hidden field to access that in your server side code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="eventOk" id="eventOk" value="" runat="server" />
```

Then you can use the following code to set the value (C#)

```
eventOk.Value = "test value";
```

and your jQuery code will be

```
$("#eventOk").val();
```

Comment: it is not server side code. I am loading page in frame uwing jquery

Comment: You question is having this line `how can I set the value in aspx page and use in js file ?`. Could you please clarify your requirement?

Comment: I am setting value in aspx page which is loaded in a iframe. a javascript file is also loaded in iframe but this js file doesnt get the value of a hidden field set by aspx method